# Unable to use 'fetchall()' with mysql.connector in python for a multi statement MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql

My MySQL Query is this:

```
query="SET @runningTotal = 0;"\
      "SELECT DateOfScan, @runningTotal := @runningTotal + totals.TotalNumberOfWorkItems AS runningTotal "\
      "FROM(SELECT DateOfScan, SUM(TotalNumberOfWorkItems) as TotalNumberOfWorkItems from metrics a, meta b where a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID and "\
     f"b.{option} like '{choice}' and a.dateofscan >= '{from_date}' and a.dateofscan <= '{to_date}' "\
     "GROUP by Month(a.DateOfScan) ASC) totals ORDER BY DateOfScan"
```

I then follow the instructions to use `multi=True` in my `cursor.execute` statement but then when I try to assign the returned values from DB with the `cursor.fetchall()` function, I get greeted by this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.

I've already found another question dealing with the same issue however the OP was not dealing with multiple statements.
I'd like to know the correct procedure to procure the response from DB with a multi statement MySQL query.

I also know the query is correct as I've tested it in XAMP's PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-statements, it's necessary to iterate over the cursor to get each result, as described in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

For example:

```
for result in cur.execute(stmt, multi=True):
    if result.with_rows:
        print('Rows for', result.statement)
        print(result.fetchall())
    else:
        print(result.rowcount, 'rows affected by', result.statement)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response SnakeCharmer!
I tried it and viewed the documentation as well, however now I'm getting a runtime error that says:
"generator raised StopIteration" and its highlighting the:
"for result in cur.execute(stmt, multi=True):" line equivalent in my IDE

Comment: That suggests that there are no results at all.  I would double-check that the SQL is definitely valid, and perhaps enable warnings on the connection and inspect them with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchwarnings.html

Comment: Temporarily avoiding the error by putting it in try/except :P

Comment: That is strange, the outputs are showing up in the console though.
*And I had also checked the query separately with XAMP and it does respond with values from DB